# How to make particular drop down linkable in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, hyperlink

how to make particular drop down linkable in HTML

```js
var countries = ["Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "Andorra", "Angola", "Anguilla", "Antigua & Barbuda", "Argentina", "Armenia", "Aruba", "Australia", "Austria", "Azerbaijan", "Bahamas", "Bahrain", "Bangladesh", "Barbados", "Belarus", "Belgium", "Belize", "Benin", "Bermuda", "Bhutan", "Bolivia", "Bosnia & Herzegovina", "Botswana", "Brazil", "British Virgin Islands", "Brunei", "Bulgaria", "Burkina Faso", "Burundi", "Cambodia", "Cameroon", "Canada", "Cape Verde", "Cayman Islands", "Central Arfrican Republic", "Chad", "Chile", "China", "Colombia", "Congo", "Cook Islands", "Costa Rica", "Cote D Ivoire", "Croatia", "Cuba", "Curacao", "Cyprus", "Czech Republic", "Denmark", "Djibouti", "Dominica", "Dominican Republic", "Ecuador", "Egypt", "El Salvador", "Equatorial Guinea", "Eritrea", "Estonia", "Ethiopia", "Falkland Islands", "Faroe Islands", "Fiji", "Finland", "France", "French Polynesia", "French West Indies", "Gabon", "Gambia", "Georgia", "Germany", "Ghana", "Gibraltar", "Greece", "Greenland", "Grenada", "Guam", "Guatemala", "Guernsey", "Guinea", "Guinea Bissau", "Guyana", "Haiti", "Honduras", "Hong Kong", "Hungary", "Iceland", "India", "Indonesia", "Iran", "Iraq", "Ireland", "Isle of Man", "Israel", "Italy", "Jamaica", "Japan", "Jersey", "Jordan", "Kazakhstan", "Kenya", "Kiribati", "Kosovo", "Kuwait", "Kyrgyzstan", "Laos", "Latvia", "Lebanon", "Lesotho", "Liberia", "Libya", "Liechtenstein", "Lithuania", "Luxembourg", "Macau", "Macedonia", "Madagascar", "Malawi", "Malaysia", "Maldives", "Mali", "Malta", "Marshall Islands", "Mauritania", "Mauritius", "Mexico", "Micronesia", "Moldova", "Monaco", "Mongolia", "Montenegro", "Montserrat", "Morocco", "Mozambique", "Myanmar", "Namibia", "Nauro", "Nepal", "Netherlands", "Netherlands Antilles", "New Caledonia", "New Zealand", "Nicaragua", "Niger", "Nigeria", "North Korea", "Norway", "Oman", "Pakistan", "Palau", "Palestine", "Panama", "Papua New Guinea", "Paraguay", "Peru", "Philippines", "Poland", "Portugal", "Puerto Rico", "Qatar", "Reunion", "Romania", "Russia", "Rwanda", "Saint Pierre & Miquelon", "Samoa", "San Marino", "Sao Tome and Principe", "Saudi Arabia", "Senegal", "Serbia", "Seychelles", "Sierra Leone", "Singapore", "Slovakia", "Slovenia", "Solomon Islands", "Somalia", "South Africa", "South Korea", "South Sudan", "Spain", "Sri Lanka", "St Kitts & Nevis", "St Lucia", "St Vincent", "Sudan", "Suriname", "Swaziland", "Sweden", "Switzerland", "Syria", "Taiwan"];

var newCountries = countries.map(el => {
  return {
    name: el,
    url: 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/' + el
  };
});
autocomplete(document.getElementById("myInput"), newCountries);


function autocomplete(inp, arr) {
  var currentFocus;
  inp.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
    var a, b, i, val = this.value;
    closeAllLists();
    if (!val) {
      return false;
    }

    currentFocus = -1;
    a = document.createElement("DIV");
    a.setAttribute("id", this.id + "autocomplete-list");
    a.setAttribute("class", "autocomplete-items");
    this.parentNode.appendChild(a);

    /*for each item in the array...*/
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

      if (arr[i].name.substr(0, val.length).toUpperCase() == val.toUpperCase()) {

        b = document.createElement("DIV");
        b.innerHTML = "<a href=\'" + arr[i].url + "\' target='_blank'><strong>" + arr[i].name.substr(0, val.length) + "</strong>" + arr[i].name.substr(val.length) + "</a>";
        b.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' value='" + arr[i].name + "'>";
        b.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
          inp.value = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
          closeAllLists();
        });
        a.appendChild(b);
      }
    }
  });

  inp.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    var x = document.getElementById(this.id + "autocomplete-list");
    if (x) x = x.getElementsByTagName("div");
    if (e.keyCode == 40) {
      currentFocus++;
      addActive(x);
    } else if (e.keyCode == 38) { //up
      currentFocus--;
      addActive(x);
    } else if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      e.preventDefault();
      if (currentFocus > -1) {
        if (x) x[currentFocus].click();
      }
    }
  });

  function addActive(x) {
    /*a function to classify an item as "active":*/
    if (!x) return false;
    removeActive(x);
    if (currentFocus >= x.length) currentFocus = 0;
    if (currentFocus < 0) currentFocus = (x.length - 1);
    x[currentFocus].classList.add("autocomplete-active");
  }

  function removeActive(x) {
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].classList.remove("autocomplete-active");
    }
  }

  function closeAllLists(elmnt) {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("autocomplete-items");
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      if (elmnt != x[i] && elmnt != inp) {
        x[i].parentNode.removeChild(x[i]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font: 16px Arial;
}

.autocomplete {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

input {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

input[type=text] {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100%;
}

input[type=submit] {
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.autocomplete-items {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-top: none;
  z-index: 99;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.autocomplete-items div {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
}

.autocomplete-items div:hover {
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
}

.autocomplete-active {
  background-color: DodgerBlue !important;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<h2>Autocomplete</h2>

<p>Start typing:</p>

<!--Make sure the form has the autocomplete function switched off:-->
<form autocomplete="off" action="/action_page.php">
  <div class="autocomplete" style="width:300px;">
    <input id="myInput" type="text" name="myCountry" placeholder="Country">
  </div>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Here in the above line how I can make the separate list linkable according to the country name . Here separate list in the sense if I type India than the list item contain that URL and when a user tap on it it opens instead of filling the input field.

```
b = document.createElement("DIV");
      b.innerHTML = "<a href=\'" + arr[i].url + "\' target='_blank'><strong>" + arr[i].name.substr(0, val.length) + "</strong>" + arr[i].name.substr(val.length) + "</a>";
      b.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' value='" + arr[i].name + "'>";
      b.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
          inp.value = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;

          closeAllLists();
      });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've done most the hard work, you just need to tell javascript to open a URL after a click on your list. The click event is already there, so just add the following line:

```
window.open(this.children[0].href ,"_self");
```

This will find the `href` from the first child of the list item clicked, and then launch the URL in the current window.

Let me know if you needed something else.

```js
var countries = ["Afghanistan","Albania","Algeria","Andorra","Angola","Anguilla","Antigua & Barbuda","Argentina","Armenia","Aruba","Australia","Austria","Azerbaijan","Bahamas","Bahrain","Bangladesh","Barbados","Belarus","Belgium","Belize","Benin","Bermuda","Bhutan","Bolivia","Bosnia & Herzegovina","Botswana","Brazil","British Virgin Islands","Brunei","Bulgaria","Burkina Faso","Burundi","Cambodia","Cameroon","Canada","Cape Verde","Cayman Islands","Central Arfrican Republic","Chad","Chile","China","Colombia","Congo","Cook Islands","Costa Rica","Cote D Ivoire","Croatia","Cuba","Curacao","Cyprus","Czech Republic","Denmark","Djibouti","Dominica","Dominican Republic","Ecuador","Egypt","El Salvador","Equatorial Guinea","Eritrea","Estonia","Ethiopia","Falkland Islands","Faroe Islands","Fiji","Finland","France","French Polynesia","French West Indies","Gabon","Gambia","Georgia","Germany","Ghana","Gibraltar","Greece","Greenland","Grenada","Guam","Guatemala","Guernsey","Guinea","Guinea Bissau","Guyana","Haiti","Honduras","Hong Kong","Hungary","Iceland","India","Indonesia","Iran","Iraq","Ireland","Isle of Man","Israel","Italy","Jamaica","Japan","Jersey","Jordan","Kazakhstan","Kenya","Kiribati","Kosovo","Kuwait","Kyrgyzstan","Laos","Latvia","Lebanon","Lesotho","Liberia","Libya","Liechtenstein","Lithuania","Luxembourg","Macau","Macedonia","Madagascar","Malawi","Malaysia","Maldives","Mali","Malta","Marshall Islands","Mauritania","Mauritius","Mexico","Micronesia","Moldova","Monaco","Mongolia","Montenegro","Montserrat","Morocco","Mozambique","Myanmar","Namibia","Nauro","Nepal","Netherlands","Netherlands Antilles","New Caledonia","New Zealand","Nicaragua","Niger","Nigeria","North Korea","Norway","Oman","Pakistan","Palau","Palestine","Panama","Papua New Guinea","Paraguay","Peru","Philippines","Poland","Portugal","Puerto Rico","Qatar","Reunion","Romania","Russia","Rwanda","Saint Pierre & Miquelon","Samoa","San Marino","Sao Tome and Principe","Saudi Arabia","Senegal","Serbia","Seychelles","Sierra Leone","Singapore","Slovakia","Slovenia","Solomon Islands","Somalia","South Africa","South Korea","South Sudan","Spain","Sri Lanka","St Kitts & Nevis","St Lucia","St Vincent","Sudan","Suriname","Swaziland","Sweden","Switzerland","Syria","Taiwan"];
    
    var newCountries = countries.map(el => {
      return {
        name: el,
        url: 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/' + el
        };
    });
    autocomplete(document.getElementById("myInput"), newCountries);
    
    
    function autocomplete(inp, arr) {
      var currentFocus;
      inp.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
          var a, b, i, val = this.value;
          closeAllLists();
          if (!val) { return false;}
    
          currentFocus = -1;
          a = document.createElement("DIV");
          a.setAttribute("id", this.id + "autocomplete-list");
          a.setAttribute("class", "autocomplete-items");
          this.parentNode.appendChild(a);
    
          /*for each item in the array...*/
          for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    
            if (arr[i].name.substr(0, val.length).toUpperCase() == val.toUpperCase()) {
    
              b = document.createElement("DIV");
              b.innerHTML = "<a href=\'" + arr[i].url + "\' target='_blank'><strong>" + arr[i].name.substr(0, val.length) + "</strong>" + arr[i].name.substr(val.length) + "</a>";
              b.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' value='" + arr[i].name + "'>";
              b.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
                  inp.value = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
                  closeAllLists();
                  window.open(this.children[0].href ,"_self");
              });
              a.appendChild(b);
            }
          }
      });
    
      inp.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
          var x = document.getElementById(this.id + "autocomplete-list");
          if (x) x = x.getElementsByTagName("div");
          if (e.keyCode == 40) {
            currentFocus++;
            addActive(x);
          } else if (e.keyCode == 38) { //up
            currentFocus--;
            addActive(x);
          } else if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (currentFocus > -1) {
              if (x) x[currentFocus].click();
            }
          }
      });
      function addActive(x) {
        /*a function to classify an item as "active":*/
        if (!x) return false;
        removeActive(x);
        if (currentFocus >= x.length) currentFocus = 0;
        if (currentFocus < 0) currentFocus = (x.length - 1);
        x[currentFocus].classList.add("autocomplete-active");
      }
      function removeActive(x) {
        for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
          x[i].classList.remove("autocomplete-active");
        }
      }
      function closeAllLists(elmnt) {
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("autocomplete-items");
        for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
          if (elmnt != x[i] && elmnt != inp) {
            x[i].parentNode.removeChild(x[i]);
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
        body { font: 16px Arial; }
    
        .autocomplete {
         position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        }
    
        input {
        border: 1px solid transparent;
        background-color: #f1f1f1;
        padding: 10px;
        font-size: 16px;
         }
    
        input[type=text] {
        background-color: #f1f1f1;
        width: 100%;
         }
    
        input[type=submit] {
        background-color: DodgerBlue;
        color: #fff;
        cursor: pointer;
          }
    
        .autocomplete-items {
        position: absolute;
         border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
         border-bottom: none;
         border-top: none;
         z-index: 99;
    
         top: 100%;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        }
    
         .autocomplete-items div {
          padding: 10px;
        cursor: pointer;
        background-color: #fff; 
        border-bottom: 1px solid #d4d4d4; 
          }
    
          .autocomplete-items div:hover {
           background-color: #e9e9e9; 
             }
    
         .autocomplete-active {
          background-color: DodgerBlue !important; 
          color: #ffffff; 
            }
```

```html
<h2>Autocomplete</h2>
    
    <p>Start typing:</p>
    
    <!--Make sure the form has the autocomplete function switched off:-->
    <form autocomplete="off" action="/action_page.php">
      <div class="autocomplete" style="width:300px;">
        <input id="myInput" type="text" name="myCountry" placeholder="Country">
      </div>
      <input type="submit">
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change the onclick function to change the window's location

```
b.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
                  inp.value = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
                  // get the value of href in tag a
                  href = this.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].href;
                  // open href in window
                  window.location.href = href;
                  closeAllLists();
              });
```

```js
var countries = ["Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "Andorra", "Angola", "Anguilla", "Antigua & Barbuda", "Argentina", "Armenia", "Aruba", "Australia", "Austria", "Azerbaijan", "Bahamas", "Bahrain", "Bangladesh", "Barbados", "Belarus", "Belgium", "Belize", "Benin", "Bermuda", "Bhutan", "Bolivia", "Bosnia & Herzegovina", "Botswana", "Brazil", "British Virgin Islands", "Brunei", "Bulgaria", "Burkina Faso", "Burundi", "Cambodia", "Cameroon", "Canada", "Cape Verde", "Cayman Islands", "Central Arfrican Republic", "Chad", "Chile", "China", "Colombia", "Congo", "Cook Islands", "Costa Rica", "Cote D Ivoire", "Croatia", "Cuba", "Curacao", "Cyprus", "Czech Republic", "Denmark", "Djibouti", "Dominica", "Dominican Republic", "Ecuador", "Egypt", "El Salvador", "Equatorial Guinea", "Eritrea", "Estonia", "Ethiopia", "Falkland Islands", "Faroe Islands", "Fiji", "Finland", "France", "French Polynesia", "French West Indies", "Gabon", "Gambia", "Georgia", "Germany", "Ghana", "Gibraltar", "Greece", "Greenland", "Grenada", "Guam", "Guatemala", "Guernsey", "Guinea", "Guinea Bissau", "Guyana", "Haiti", "Honduras", "Hong Kong", "Hungary", "Iceland", "India", "Indonesia", "Iran", "Iraq", "Ireland", "Isle of Man", "Israel", "Italy", "Jamaica", "Japan", "Jersey", "Jordan", "Kazakhstan", "Kenya", "Kiribati", "Kosovo", "Kuwait", "Kyrgyzstan", "Laos", "Latvia", "Lebanon", "Lesotho", "Liberia", "Libya", "Liechtenstein", "Lithuania", "Luxembourg", "Macau", "Macedonia", "Madagascar", "Malawi", "Malaysia", "Maldives", "Mali", "Malta", "Marshall Islands", "Mauritania", "Mauritius", "Mexico", "Micronesia", "Moldova", "Monaco", "Mongolia", "Montenegro", "Montserrat", "Morocco", "Mozambique", "Myanmar", "Namibia", "Nauro", "Nepal", "Netherlands", "Netherlands Antilles", "New Caledonia", "New Zealand", "Nicaragua", "Niger", "Nigeria", "North Korea", "Norway", "Oman", "Pakistan", "Palau", "Palestine", "Panama", "Papua New Guinea", "Paraguay", "Peru", "Philippines", "Poland", "Portugal", "Puerto Rico", "Qatar", "Reunion", "Romania", "Russia", "Rwanda", "Saint Pierre & Miquelon", "Samoa", "San Marino", "Sao Tome and Principe", "Saudi Arabia", "Senegal", "Serbia", "Seychelles", "Sierra Leone", "Singapore", "Slovakia", "Slovenia", "Solomon Islands", "Somalia", "South Africa", "South Korea", "South Sudan", "Spain", "Sri Lanka", "St Kitts & Nevis", "St Lucia", "St Vincent", "Sudan", "Suriname", "Swaziland", "Sweden", "Switzerland", "Syria", "Taiwan"];

var newCountries = countries.map(el => {
  return {
    name: el,
    url: 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/' + el
  };
});
autocomplete(document.getElementById("myInput"), newCountries);


function autocomplete(inp, arr) {
  var currentFocus;
  inp.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
    var a, b, i, val = this.value;
    closeAllLists();
    if (!val) {
      return false;
    }

    currentFocus = -1;
    a = document.createElement("DIV");
    a.setAttribute("id", this.id + "autocomplete-list");
    a.setAttribute("class", "autocomplete-items");
    this.parentNode.appendChild(a);

    /*for each item in the array...*/
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

      if (arr[i].name.substr(0, val.length).toUpperCase() == val.toUpperCase()) {

        b = document.createElement("DIV");
        b.innerHTML = "<a href=\'" + arr[i].url + "\' target='_blank'><strong>" + arr[i].name.substr(0, val.length) + "</strong>" + arr[i].name.substr(val.length) + "</a>";
        b.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' value='" + arr[i].name + "'>";
        b.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
          inp.value = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
          closeAllLists();
          href = this.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].href;
          location.href = href;
        });
        a.appendChild(b);
      }
    }
  });

  inp.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    var x = document.getElementById(this.id + "autocomplete-list");
    if (x) x = x.getElementsByTagName("div");
    if (e.keyCode == 40) {
      currentFocus++;
      addActive(x);
    } else if (e.keyCode == 38) { //up
      currentFocus--;
      addActive(x);
    } else if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      e.preventDefault();
      if (currentFocus > -1) {
        if (x) x[currentFocus].click();
      }
    }
  });

  function addActive(x) {
    /*a function to classify an item as "active":*/
    if (!x) return false;
    removeActive(x);
    if (currentFocus >= x.length) currentFocus = 0;
    if (currentFocus < 0) currentFocus = (x.length - 1);
    x[currentFocus].classList.add("autocomplete-active");
  }

  function removeActive(x) {
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].classList.remove("autocomplete-active");
    }
  }

  function closeAllLists(elmnt) {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("autocomplete-items");
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      if (elmnt != x[i] && elmnt != inp) {
        x[i].parentNode.removeChild(x[i]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font: 16px Arial;
}

.autocomplete {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

input {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

input[type=text] {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100%;
}

input[type=submit] {
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.autocomplete-items {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-top: none;
  z-index: 99;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.autocomplete-items div {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
}

.autocomplete-items div:hover {
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
}

.autocomplete-active {
  background-color: DodgerBlue !important;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<h2>Autocomplete</h2>

<p>Start typing:</p>

<!--Make sure the form has the autocomplete function switched off:-->
<form autocomplete="off" action="/action_page.php">
  <div class="autocomplete" style="width:300px;">
    <input id="myInput" type="text" name="myCountry" placeholder="Country">
  </div>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

```js
var countries = ["Afghanistan","Albania","Algeria","Andorra","Angola","Anguilla","Antigua & Barbuda","Argentina","Armenia","Aruba","Australia","Austria","Azerbaijan","Bahamas","Bahrain","Bangladesh","Barbados","Belarus","Belgium","Belize","Benin","Bermuda","Bhutan","Bolivia","Bosnia & Herzegovina","Botswana","Brazil","British Virgin Islands","Brunei","Bulgaria","Burkina Faso","Burundi","Cambodia","Cameroon","Canada","Cape Verde","Cayman Islands","Central Arfrican Republic","Chad","Chile","China","Colombia","Congo","Cook Islands","Costa Rica","Cote D Ivoire","Croatia","Cuba","Curacao","Cyprus","Czech Republic","Denmark","Djibouti","Dominica","Dominican Republic","Ecuador","Egypt","El Salvador","Equatorial Guinea","Eritrea","Estonia","Ethiopia","Falkland Islands","Faroe Islands","Fiji","Finland","France","French Polynesia","French West Indies","Gabon","Gambia","Georgia","Germany","Ghana","Gibraltar","Greece","Greenland","Grenada","Guam","Guatemala","Guernsey","Guinea","Guinea Bissau","Guyana","Haiti","Honduras","Hong Kong","Hungary","Iceland","India","Indonesia","Iran","Iraq","Ireland","Isle of Man","Israel","Italy","Jamaica","Japan","Jersey","Jordan","Kazakhstan","Kenya","Kiribati","Kosovo","Kuwait","Kyrgyzstan","Laos","Latvia","Lebanon","Lesotho","Liberia","Libya","Liechtenstein","Lithuania","Luxembourg","Macau","Macedonia","Madagascar","Malawi","Malaysia","Maldives","Mali","Malta","Marshall Islands","Mauritania","Mauritius","Mexico","Micronesia","Moldova","Monaco","Mongolia","Montenegro","Montserrat","Morocco","Mozambique","Myanmar","Namibia","Nauro","Nepal","Netherlands","Netherlands Antilles","New Caledonia","New Zealand","Nicaragua","Niger","Nigeria","North Korea","Norway","Oman","Pakistan","Palau","Palestine","Panama","Papua New Guinea","Paraguay","Peru","Philippines","Poland","Portugal","Puerto Rico","Qatar","Reunion","Romania","Russia","Rwanda","Saint Pierre & Miquelon","Samoa","San Marino","Sao Tome and Principe","Saudi Arabia","Senegal","Serbia","Seychelles","Sierra Leone","Singapore","Slovakia","Slovenia","Solomon Islands","Somalia","South Africa","South Korea","South Sudan","Spain","Sri Lanka","St Kitts & Nevis","St Lucia","St Vincent","Sudan","Suriname","Swaziland","Sweden","Switzerland","Syria","Taiwan"];
    
    var newCountries = countries.map(el => {
      return {
        name: el,
        url: 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/' + el
        };
    });
    autocomplete(document.getElementById("myInput"), newCountries);
    
    
    function autocomplete(inp, arr) {
      var currentFocus;
      inp.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
          var a, b, i, val = this.value;
          closeAllLists();
          if (!val) { return false;}
    
          currentFocus = -1;
          a = document.createElement("DIV");
          a.setAttribute("id", this.id + "autocomplete-list");
          a.setAttribute("class", "autocomplete-items");
          this.parentNode.appendChild(a);
    
          /*for each item in the array...*/
          for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    
            if (arr[i].name.substr(0, val.length).toUpperCase() == val.toUpperCase()) {
    
              b = document.createElement("DIV");
              b.innerHTML = "<a href=\'" + arr[i].url + "\' target='_blank'><strong>" + arr[i].name.substr(0, val.length) + "</strong>" + arr[i].name.substr(val.length) + "</a>";
              b.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' value='" + arr[i].name + "'>";
              b.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
                  inp.value = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
                  href = this.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].href;
                  window.location.href = href;
                  closeAllLists();
              });
              a.appendChild(b);
            }
          }
      });
    
      inp.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
          var x = document.getElementById(this.id + "autocomplete-list");
          if (x) x = x.getElementsByTagName("div");
          if (e.keyCode == 40) {
            currentFocus++;
            addActive(x);
          } else if (e.keyCode == 38) { //up
            currentFocus--;
            addActive(x);
          } else if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (currentFocus > -1) {
              if (x) x[currentFocus].click();
            }
          }
      });
      function addActive(x) {
        /*a function to classify an item as "active":*/
        if (!x) return false;
        removeActive(x);
        if (currentFocus >= x.length) currentFocus = 0;
        if (currentFocus < 0) currentFocus = (x.length - 1);
        x[currentFocus].classList.add("autocomplete-active");
      }
      function removeActive(x) {
        for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
          x[i].classList.remove("autocomplete-active");
        }
      }
      function closeAllLists(elmnt) {
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("autocomplete-items");
        for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
          if (elmnt != x[i] && elmnt != inp) {
            x[i].parentNode.removeChild(x[i]);
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
        body { font: 16px Arial; }
    
        .autocomplete {
         position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        }
    
        input {
        border: 1px solid transparent;
        background-color: #f1f1f1;
        padding: 10px;
        font-size: 16px;
         }
    
        input[type=text] {
        background-color: #f1f1f1;
        width: 100%;
         }
    
        input[type=submit] {
        background-color: DodgerBlue;
        color: #fff;
        cursor: pointer;
          }
    
        .autocomplete-items {
        position: absolute;
         border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
         border-bottom: none;
         border-top: none;
         z-index: 99;
    
         top: 100%;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        }
    
         .autocomplete-items div {
          padding: 10px;
        cursor: pointer;
        background-color: #fff; 
        border-bottom: 1px solid #d4d4d4; 
          }
    
          .autocomplete-items div:hover {
           background-color: #e9e9e9; 
             }
    
         .autocomplete-active {
          background-color: DodgerBlue !important; 
          color: #ffffff; 
            }
```

```html
<h2>Autocomplete</h2>
    
    <p>Start typing:</p>
    
    <!--Make sure the form has the autocomplete function switched off:-->
    <form autocomplete="off" action="/action_page.php">
      <div class="autocomplete" style="width:300px;">
        <input id="myInput" type="text" name="myCountry" placeholder="Country">
      </div>
      <input type="submit">
    </form>
```